# VS2015 C++ : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2015

I try to make NCORR library work on VS2015 C++. The library was originally written on Linux.

As part of the library there is code similar to

```
#include <chrono>

template<typename T_container>
struct container_traits {
    typedef typename T_container::container              nonconst_container;
};


template <typename T_container>
class base_region {
public:

    typedef typename container_traits<T_container>::nonconst_container nonconst_container;

    template<typename T_container2>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename container_traits<T_container2>::nonconst_container, typename nonconst_container>::value, base_region&>::type operator=(const base_region<T_container2>&);
};

template <typename T_container>
template <typename T_container2>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename container_traits<T_container2>::nonconst_container, typename base_region<T_container>::nonconst_container>::value, base_region<T_container>&>::type base_region<T_container>::operator=(const base_region<T_container2>& reg) {
    return *this;
}


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the code on VS2015 win32 console application, I get

```
C2244   'base_region<T_container>::operator =': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration  ConsoleApplication5
```

I think the problem is `typename nonconst_container` in declaration vs `typename base_region<T_container>::nonconst_container` in definition.

Do you know what is wrong and how can I make the code work?

Comment: If you remove the `typename` in `typename nonconst_container` in the member declaration, this compiles in coliru with [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30ab305e8fc307c3) and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae3cd31c437b01e6). It still fails in VS2015, so I think it has to be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Ok, I will report it to Microsoft. Can you think of any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `typename nonconst_container` is ill-formed. `typename` is only allowed before a qualified name.

MSVC seems to have problems matching `nonconst_container` in the class template definition and the `typename base_region<T_container>::nonconst_container` in the out-of-class member function definition.

A workaround (which is also shorter) is to use a *trailing-return-type*:

```
template <typename T_container>
template <typename T_container2>
auto base_region<T_container>::operator=(const base_region<T_container2>& reg)
  -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename container_traits<T_container2>::nonconst_container,
                                          nonconst_container>::value, base_region&>::type 
                                       // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^
{
   //...
}
```

Everything after `base_region<T_container>::operator=` gets looked up just like a name used in the member function body (in particular, it will first look at class members), so you can just write `nonconst_container` and `base_region&`, and happily sidestep the MSVC bug.