# C++ : Using constexpr to alias template parameters, causing function definitions to not match to declarations

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

I'm trying to get something like template forwarding based on a precompiler variable.  However, I'm running into strange compile errors, so I'll try to give an example of what I'm working on.

I have a matrix class that takes two template parameters, and the way it uses its template parameters is based on a precompiler variable that determines whether we are in a column-major environment or a row-major environment.

```
template<size_t vectorLength>
class Vector {
//... Implementation stuff
}

#define ROW_MAJOR

template<size_t rows, size_t columns>
class Matrix {

#if defined(ROW_MAJOR)
std::array<Vector<columns>, rows> m_vectorArray;
#else
std::array<Vector<rows>, columns> m_vectorArray;
#endif

//... Other stuff
}
```

As you might be able to imagine, this leads to a lot of `#if` and `#else` precompiler statements everywhere in my code, so instead of doing that, I thought about "forwarding" the template parameters in one spot, and referring to those template parameters.  For example ...

```
#define ROW_MAJOR

template<size_t rows, size_t columns>
class Matrix {

#if defined(ROW_MAJOR)
static constexpr size_t numberOfVectors = rows;
static constexpr size_t vectorLength = columns;
#else
static constexpr size_t numberOfVectors = columns;
static constexpr size_t vectorLength = rows;
#endif

std::array<Vector<vectorLength>, numberOfVectors> m_vectorArray
//... Other stuff
}
```

And that was working great, until I had to return single vectors.  I tried to declare a function inside of Matrix as such:

```
template<size_t rows, size_t columns>
class Matrix {

//...Insert stuff from above
Vector<Matrix::vectorLength> GetVector(size_t index) const;
// ... Other stuff
}
```

And in the include file, the function was defined as follows:

```
template<size_t rows, size_t columns>
Vector<Matrix<rows, columns>::vectorLength> Matrix<rows, columns>::GetVector(size_t index) const
{
//... Implementation
}
```

And when I went to compile it, I had the following error

> error C2244: 'Matrix::GetVector': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Which when this error gets reported by Visual Studio, it proceeds to try and help me out by printing the definition signature and all the declaration signatures of the function `GetVector`.

```
note: definition
note: 'Vector<Matrix<rows,columns>::vectorLength> Matrix<rows,columns>::GetVector(size_t index)'
note: existing declarations
note: 'Vector<Matrix<rows,columns>::vectorLength> Matrix<rows,columns>::GetVector(size_t index)'
```

The two match up character for character (I know this is an example, but I've copy and pasted both of the notes that I'm getting in my actual code, compared them, and they match character for character), So I guess my question is ... is this a misuse of `constexpr`?  Is there something I'm forgetting to write?  Is this a bug in Visual Studio's compiler (I've run into a lot of VS bugs dealing with `constexpr` already).  Or is this a foolish way to go about this?

Some notes: I tried putting the definition in the header file and everything compiled fine.  It's not an issue of "don't put template definitions in cpp files", the header and include files are bundled into the same include package, so the definition is guaranteed to be there with the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably another manifestation of [this MSVC bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980926/vs2015-c-unable-to-match-function-definition-to-an-existing-declaration/33981566#33981566), though that one has a nested type while here you are just using a member constant.

Use a trailing return type to work around - it's shorter, too:

```
auto Matrix<rows, columns>::GetVector(size_t index) const
     -> Vector<Matrix::vectorLength> {
//...
}
```

Also, you can just write `vectorLength` instead of `Matrix::vectorLength` if you do it in both places.