# (MSVC) When implementing template method of template class outside of the class, C2244: Unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Running into an issue with some code that compiles on GCC and Clang, but not MSVC (VS2022). Seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980926/vs2015-c-unable-to-match-function-definition-to-an-existing-declaration/33981566#33981566), but that was several years ago and this issue is specifically caused by the use of `derived_from_specialization_of` in the method template, so I'm not sure if it's the same issue.

I'm wondering what the reason for this is, and if the issue is with my code or MSVC.

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIJIA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/ilpGQIhYZEsMXGJtpj2jgJCBEzEBNk%2BfgF2mA6Z9Y0ExRHRsfFJCg1NLbntY32hA2VDiQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CbbbmgMG8kECifYJhoAgvcPBJgsyQavx6ev75%2BY3zOBgUCgAdODbod9kwQYcACpvD5MV6kKHAsHgw4PYjAG7bO6PABuqDw6EOWGIeEJmHQAH0qMRUCxaQpkp08GI8AAvZGZWl4P4Qc6jeGI/4nNzY3Hg0G3cwANkWJysj2evyRXwl0NhcNR6v%2BgO1GNl%2BLRMIUor%2ByMwcse50uBHJsSpNPpjOZrPZnJ5tQYtNQVG%2BABFDsRMABHLx4MMKIUCEVwhWHAiLY4JFUPQ5Zp2U6l0hlMlls5Ac2jc3kCfl/CUIq2vW4QFPK54mBJB5uqx7662G9Hw20PI1Ylvp57JLxRMvIEDPbNYiCpk4hrBUJheWgEDtPNtbtVinsSiku/Puotess%2BvkBiVPU2J/HPIdWbYZvd1gGH515t2Fz0l70Vn616nM%2B2D9g%2Bdp9m4I4ZuOk54NOs7Zm4C7Bk6q7rpuL4ju22Gdi8%2B6aqcR7fgWHrFqW5a%2Bv6VA3pC94EoOfavqOjxwVOM6PHOFioUu6Frhuu5cdm3ZEW4JGumRZ7/hegE0RKoGHHIA73AAnNBpzKaaABiqCoAuQmZiJhEfsRX6Saef6UZelbAW4ilaYxakaW4jmHBYjQGcJWathmc5zmGBBrAwhwuY5Bl4UZPk7qqO6RW%2BGqmeJ5knr%2BFEAdRdm3mBDEJQan65hZaXnlRV60SBkKOc8YWQs%2BbgMSAIC6fpi6xX52aBcFoUSuFSrxTFTyPBwyy0JwACsvB%2BBwWikKgnDQZY1iHAoqzrB%2BZjbDwpAEJow3LAA1iA2wJKCXBjVw2xjfKGhmKpqmSAAHNs%2BicJIk27bNnC8AoIAaNtu3LHAsBIOc/DECwhgbOQlBoO8dCxD9sCw8k8PEAAkugKAGEYtIEMQXgMPts1XJkP0cAAtKM6BLqYi2WGYWiA8jqMYyAuLMMkCgIKgBDE76ZOUwQ1PbEGtNWPTGiHOTVD2pgVwKOT%2BBMMADBpI4yAK1gVwIEuZiHMNpBxnD9Do5jhLIMkyS0oSXCqbS/yjLSqjytIqAk/GnCC5jYvWAze2BPgRCUpjXD6IYwCsz7lj6HgUSIwuI3je9028HNHAeAwYMQxcAIAGp4JgADusSHBAuCECQxwbVwqbbAA9FwM07SnizLAgmBMBSlAHRIZigg9j0u9sqkJBoGjnaPSSjRwb2kFNM1p99v3/S3hswIgKBMijJvQ0b29DOblvW7b9vWo7zvSDQG4I5QUQfVEoSNAAnpwW2w2wggAPIMLQL8p6QWBs7AHEP/fAYYujUjJjNTAqhOheFeK/XgoRXjTxmmWKIxBn4eCwB9PGApEHLCoAYXE%2Bci6fzZFNLa/BBAiDEOwKQMhBCKBUOof%2BuhQ7Y2MNYawMc47wGWG7fmnsqYoG4RLb61ROi%2BhcAwdwnhWh6GCLMUo5Q9CpHSL6CYfhQ7qMKAwfoKihihw6F0Oo0wtF6BMb6HoTQDGDDiMY8x8jciON6HY%2BYDjlgrTWBsPQeNMCbB4InDgE054fTThfQ4LAFDm0ODbVSoIHaOggAtcWNhDjlyDlXTaqIPDGxLjsGuvBm6Mx7mYSQoI7pVOqTU%2BUL0Z7JwXl9Wwy8SkGyBhvVYBBxy8woHvVG4RWCbEidE2J8TElnwILwGkFdg56GocIUQ4gGELOYWoD67DSCF0wckAh9TQnz1TpwT%2B8CemHADIcEZMTkBxNthM14IoUlb1RtkopK9SmkEOmYMa9TZ6HM%2BhwJef02mt3qWYRpRzAXvP9tSYg6RnCSCAA%3D%3D)

Example:

```
#include <concepts>

template <template <class...> class Template, class... Args>
void derived_from_specialization_impl(const Template<Args...>&);

template <class T, template <class...> class Template>
concept derived_from_specialization_of = requires(const T& t) {
    derived_from_specialization_impl<Template>(t);
};

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
};

template <derived_from_specialization_of<A> T>
class B;

template <derived_from_specialization_of<B> T>
class C
{
public:
    C() = default;
};

template <derived_from_specialization_of<A> T>
class B
{
public:
    B() = default;

    template <derived_from_specialization_of<B> U>
    C<U> Foo();

    template <derived_from_specialization_of<B> U>
    C<U> Bar()
    {
        return C<U>();
    }
};

template <derived_from_specialization_of<A> T>
template <derived_from_specialization_of<B> U>
C<U> B<T>::Foo() 
{
    return C<U>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what the reason for this is, and if the issue is with my code or MSVC.

This seems to be a bug in MSVC. You've correctly provided the **out-of-class definition** for the member function template `Foo<>`.

Using `auto` and **trailing return type** doesn't seem to solve the issue in msvc. You can file a [bug report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/how-to-report-a-problem-with-the-visual-cpp-toolset?view=msvc-170) for this.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @康桓瑋 No, in this case this is suitable for an answer as the OP is looking for confirmation if there is something wrong in the code or a bug in msvc. Moreover, comments might get deleted in the future. So better to write whatever you think as an answer as long as it answers OP's queries.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know I'm not missing something with `auto`. I just found a [similar bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C2244-cannot-match-specialised-return-ty/1419427?entry=problem&space=62) on the VS Developer Community from a couple weeks ago.